# move семантика до 11 стандарта

Tags: c++, c++98

Как поместить в `data_new` объект `data_old` без копирования последнего, т.е. переместить его? Стандарт 98.

```
Data foo() {
    Data data_old;
    //...
    return data_old;
}

int main() {
    Data data_new = foo();
}
```

Comment: передайте объект внутрь функции. Либо надейтесь, что компилятор все оптимизирует и так.

Comment: Во-первых, `Data data_old();`??? Это объявление функции, а не объекта. Во-вторых, современные стандарты в такой ситуации отдают предпочтение RVO, а не перемещению.

Comment: @AnT будем считать это досадным недоразумением. Подправил код.

Answer (score 6):

Использовать оптимизацию не ниже `-O1` и полагаться на *copy elision* — конструирование объекта прямо на области стека для `data_new`.

Оптимизация возможна благодаря компиляции возврата сложных типов в передачу функции неявного параметра-указателя на переменную, принимающую результат. Пример:

```
struct Foo {int a;};

Foo bar(int a)
{
    Foo result;
    result.a = a;
    return result;
}

void baz()
{
    Foo field = bar(12);
}
```

Без оптимизаций это будет выглядеть на низком уровне примерно так:

```
struct Foo {int a;};

void __cdecl bar(Foo* __out, int a)
{
    Foo result;
    result.a = a;

    new(__out) Foo(result); // Вызов конструктора копирования
}

void __cdecl baz()
{
    Foo field;
    bar(&field, 12);
}
```

С *copy elision* `bar` станет таким:

```
void __cdecl bar(Foo* __out, int a)
{
    __out->a = a;
}
```

Comment: "передачу функции неявного параметра-указателя на переменную, принимающую результат" - но это RVO. А автор хочет "move семантику". Это совершенно разные вещи.

Comment: @AnT, какая move-семантика в стандарте 98 года? Автор даже уточнил версию в вопросе.

Comment: Ым... Ну так в этом же весь смысл вопроса (!): как сделать некое подобие move semantics в С++98, где ее не было. (Move semantics, разумеется, была и в С++98 и в С, просто "ручная" - без поддержки от rvalue references. Один хрестоматийный пример "ручной" реализации уже приведен @Harry `std::auto_ptr::auto_ptr_ref`)

Comment: @AnT, тогда только через указатели (в том числе умные), как указал @Harry. И то, даже `auto_ptr` не перемещает объект, а просто владеет им.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr::auto_ptr_ref` - это способ перемещения самого `std::auto_ptr`.То есть в упоминаемом примере с `std::auto_ptr::auto_ptr_ref` в качестве "объекта" подразумевается сам `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: @AnT, тогда да, согласен.

Comment: Это откуда такой выхлоп кода получился с `__cdecl`?

Answer (score 3):

В качестве дополнения.

Можно вспомнить, что костылем для семантики перемещения до C++11 был `auto_ptr`, и сыграть с ним...

...но замечу, что Мейерс в "Эффективном и современном C++" рекомендовал не полагаться на перемещение при возврате из функции. Так что постарайтесь, чтобы не было нескольких путей возврата из функции, и возвращался один объект - этого должно быть достаточно для оптимизации.

И еще - на всякий случай:

```
Data foo() {
    Data data_old();   
    //...
    return data_old;
}
```

В первой строке у вас - объявление функции `data_old`. Надеюсь, это опечатка только в вопросе.

Comment: Опечатку в вопросе поправили.