# Реализация функций-геттеров

Tags: c++, классы, c++11

Как корректно реализовывать функции-геттеры? Я имею ввиду возвращаемое значение. Так:

```
std::shared_ptr<const number_t> number () const noexcept
{
    return std::make_shared<const number_t> (this->m_number);
}
```

Или так (в стиле vector::at):

```
const auto & number () const noexcept
{
    return this->m_number;
}
```

`m_number` - поле пользовательского типа, а не стандартного.

Какой вариант считается хорошим стилем сейчас / безопаснее / более удобен и т.п.?

Comment: А зачем вы возвращаете указатель с разделяемым владением? Да ещё и константный, что в случае примитивного типа абсолютно бессмысленно.

Comment: @Arhad можно и `unique_ptr`... Мой вопрос в том надо ли использовать в геттерах дополнительные обертки smart-pointer-ов или же достаточно обойтись ссылкой на `const`? Ну или еще как-то. И речь конечно идет о не стандартном типе.

Comment: А что именно вы возвращаете? Простое значение - это одно, просто верните копию. Какой-то объект посерьезнее - вероятно, имеет смысл константная ссылка. Словом, как любят писать американцы, серебряной пули не существует. Делайте то, *что наилучшим образом отвечает стоящей перед вами задаче*. Очень может быть, что вам вообще геттер не нужен, а нужны открытые члены! Не нужно проявлять догматизм и начетничество (кто постарше - те меня поймут :))

Comment: @Harry https://toster.ru/q/331110 вот эту статью мне скинул студент, с вопросом - а почему бы не сделать как указано там, в комментарии, через умные указатели. Я, собственно, пользовался ссылками на const и мне их хватало. Поле не тривиального типа, геттер действительно нужен. Вопрос был только в применимости обертки типа unique_ptr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Умный указатель нужен только в том случае, если у нас есть переменная, лежащая в куче, и надо безопасно управлять её временем жизни (то есть с одной стороны не допустить утечки, а с другой — не уничтожить эту переменную раньше времени; именно отсюда и растут ноги понятия «владение» — переменная будет уничтожена только при уничтожении её текущего владельца).

В вашем же случае значение не является какой-то уникальной сущностью, а потому ничего страшного в создании дубликата не будет — мы не различаем между собой оригинальное число и его копию. Поэтому спокойно возвращайте величину по значению, без константных ссылок и указателей.

*Я вам больше скажу — компилятор влёгкую оптимизирует возврат значения. Если это примитивный тип, то он просто записывается в регистр процессора; если нет — применяется RVO (оптимизация возвращаемого значения, частный случай copy elision, о котором я писал в [одном из своих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621288/208074)).*

Возврат по указателю (неважно, обычному или умному) нужен только в том случае, когда мы работаем с *сущностями*. К примеру, копия графического элемента управления (GUI control) или объекта в игровом мире — это уже новые объекты, не имеющие отношения к своим оригиналам.

Comment: Вы написали - возвращать величину по значению, но я всегда практиковал, что если это вектор или еще что-то потенциально большое то использовать ссылку на константу. Чтобы избежать копирования. Не очень понял, как RVO к большому вектору применится, ведь идеологически копирование требуется?

Comment: @Jenssen, ваша правда, упустил это из виду. В этом случае да, константная ссылка уместна (но при условии, если объект будет гарантированно жить дольше пользователей этого вектора, что скорее всего соблюдается).

Comment: И еще не надо забывать о многопоточности и может ли этот m_number быть модифицированом при запросе его из другого потока