# Как работает такой копирующий конструктор?

Tags: c++, c++11, конструктор-копирования

Есть конструктор копирования:

```
Implementation(const Implementation &  other) :
    Implementation(other.clone())
{}
```

И есть функция `clone()`:

```
Implementation Implementation::clone() const 
{
    return Implementation(this->number(), this->string(), this->vector());
}
```

Конструктор перемещения:

```
Implementation(      Implementation && other) noexcept :
    Implementation()
{
    this->swap(other);
}
```

Не понимаю, почему не происходит вызов конструктора перемещения в строке `Implementation(other.clone())` (конструктор перемещения определен). Ведь функция `clone()` возвращает просто копию объекта, для которого она вызывается. Что вызывается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компилятор имеет полное право [применять *copy elision*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621288/208074), то есть заменять перемещение на конструирование объекта прямо по месту его дальнейшего присвоения.

Для подтверждения своих слов я [воспользовался онлайн-компилятором](https://godbolt.org/g/zDiUUb):

Исходный код:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Implementation
{
private:
    int number() const;
    std::string string() const;
    std::vector<int> vector() const;

public:
    Implementation();
    Implementation(int, std::string, std::vector<int>);

    Implementation(const Implementation &  other);
    Implementation(Implementation &&  other) noexcept;

    Implementation clone() const;
    void swap(Implementation& other);
};


Implementation::Implementation(const Implementation &  other) :
    Implementation(other.clone())
{}

Implementation Implementation::Implementation::clone() const 
{
    return Implementation(this->number(), this->string(), this->vector());
}

Implementation::Implementation(Implementation && other) noexcept :
    Implementation()
{
    this->swap(other);
}
```

Скомпилированный результат интересующей нас функции на языке ассемблера Intel x86_64:

```
Implementation::Implementation(Implementation const&):
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 16
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rsi
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]    
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     rsi, rdx
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    Implementation::clone() const
    nop
    leave
    ret
```

Как можно заметить, компилятор действительно применил указанный мной приём. Указатель `this` передаётся через регистр `(E/R)CX`. То есть `Implementation::Implementation(Implementation const&)` как принял `this` (в случае с конструктором он указывает на неинициализированную область памяти под объект), так и передаёт его дальше, в `clone()` без каких-либо модификаций.

Comment: Я заметил, что, если добавить `std::move` в указанную строку, то вызов такого к-ра все-таки произойдет. Получается такое добавление запрещает компилятору проводить подобную оптимизацию?

Comment: @Jenssen, да, явным использованием `std::move()` вы указываете компилятору, что вам требуется именно перемещение, с обязательным вызовом вашего конструктора (в котором может быть взаимодействие с операционной системой, например). И ещё, я дополнил ответ.